# My 2d array isnt printing the results correctly

Tags: java, arrays, loops, histogram, counter

So basically my code should count the number of each alphabet in the txt file called "input" and create a histogram accordingly.So what i did was that i created a method which makes the whole text file in lower case and used the ascii code to count the number of each alphabet in a method called "formarray" which basically  returns an array of size 26 and each positon in it contains the number of occurence of the letters in the text file (starting from position zero which corresponds to 'a' till position 25 which is for z). For the Histogram, i created a 2d array called str in which the first row contained the alphabet letters only and all the other rows where to hold "*" whenever the letter in a certain column occurred. However im not getting the correct shape of the histogram although the array which i named "ww" contains the right number of each alphabet occurenece.

```
package Assign;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class assign1 {
    //
    public static void print1d (int [] x) {
        for (int i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
            System.out.print(x[i]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");

    }
    public static void print1d (String [] x) {
        for (int i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
            System.out.print(x[i]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public static int [] formarray (String x) {
        int [] thecounter = new int [26];
        int counter=0;
        int pointer=0;

        for (int i=0;i<26;i++) {
            for (int p=0;p<x.length();p++) {
                int charint= x.charAt(p);
                if ((charint<=122&charint>=97)) {
                    if ((i+97)==charint) {
                        counter=counter+1;
                    }
                }
            }
            thecounter[i]=counter;
            counter=0;

        }
        return thecounter;

    }
    public static int countthewords(String x) {//method to count words in a string 
        int countwords = 0;
        if (x.length()== 0) {
            return countwords;
        } else {
            while (x.length() != 0) {
                if (x.charAt(0) != ' ') {
                    while (x.charAt(0) != ' ') {
                        x = x.substring(1);
                    }
                    countwords++;

                } else
                    x = x.substring(1);

            }
            return countwords;
        }

    }

    //

public static int countletters(String a) {

        if (a.length()==0) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (a.charAt(0)>=97&&a.charAt(0)<=122) {
            return countletters(a.substring(1))+1;
        }
        else 
            return countletters(a.substring(1))+0;
    }



    public static void Print2d (String [][]a) {
        for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
            for (int j=0;j<a[i].length;j++) {
                if (a[i][j]!=null)
                System.out.print(a[i][j]+" ");
            }
System.out.println("");
        }
    }


    public static String LowerCaseAll(String w) {// a method to change everything to a lower case 
        String spare="";

        for (int i =0;i<w.length();i++){
            char t = (char) w.charAt(i);
             if ((t>=65&t<=90)||(t<=122&t>=97)) {
            char y =(char) w.charAt(i);
            if (y<=90) {
                y= (char) ((char) y+32);
                spare=spare+y;
            }else spare=spare+w.charAt(i);
             }
             else 
                 spare=spare+w.charAt(i);
         }
return spare;
    }
    // 
    public static String [] theletterstring() {
        String [] r= new String [26];
        for (int i=97;i<123;i++) {
            char c =( (char) i);
            String g = c+"";
        r[i-97]=g;
        }
        return r;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String [][]trial=new String [6][3];
        for(int q=0;q<trial.length;q++) {
            for (int z=0;z<trial[q].length;z++ ) {
                if (q==3&&z==2)
                    trial [q][z]=null;
                else
                trial [q][z]="*";
            }
        }
        //Print2d(trial);
        int wordcount = 0;
        BufferedReader br;
        String cbr; // this string will contain the line im currently reading
        String savecbr = "";// saves every line i read in this string so that at the end i will have
                            // everything in this string;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));//read the file given which is "input.txt" in our case 
        cbr=br.readLine();

        while (cbr!= null) {
            savecbr = savecbr + " " +cbr;
            cbr=br.readLine();
        }


        wordcount = countthewords(savecbr);
String savecbr1=LowerCaseAll(savecbr);
int ss= countletters(savecbr1);
int []ww =formarray(savecbr1);
String[][] str= new String  [savecbr.length()] [26];
for (int t=0;t<26;t++) {

}
for (int f=0;f<26;f++) {
    char c = (char) ((char)f+97);
    str[0][f]=""+c;
}

//String[][] str= new String  [savecbr.length()] [26];
for (int t=0;t<26;t++) {
    for (int h=1;h<=ww[t];h++) {
        str[h][t]= "*";
    }

}
print1d(ww);
Print2d(str);
//System.out.println(ww[1]);

    }
}
```

Comment: If I'm right, you're trying to read an input file and trying to print the number of occurrences of every alphabet. Am I correct?

Comment: @Sridhar exactly, and then im trying to create a histogram to visualize the number of occurence of every alphabet. But the histogram isnt printing the correct results

Comment: And, you have problem with printing the histogram only right? At `Print2d()` method

Comment: @Sridhar im not sure if the problem is in Print2d or the very last two for loops

Comment: I've added an answer. It prints the histogram properly for me. Please check the same and accept the answer, if it resolves your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when printing the 2d array, You're just skipping the `null` values. This messes up the values to be printed on specific indexes properly (making the histogram of h to be printed for d). Just printing spaces in the null values will cause the histogram to print properly. Just add an `else` block to print a space for the null values, and you will be good to go.

```
public static void Print2d (String [][]a) {
    for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
        for (int j=0;j<a[i].length;j++) {
            if (a[i][j]!=null)
                System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
            else 
                System.out.print("  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

***Output:***

```
40 4 42 0 0 0 0 1 3 6 18 15 0 18 3 0 0 0 29 1 2 0 1 0 0 0  
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 
* * *         * * * * *   * *       * * *   *       
* * *           * * * *   * *       *   *           
* * *           * * * *   * *       *               
* * *             * * *   *         *               
*   *             * * *   *         *               
*   *             * * *   *         *               
*   *               * *   *         *               
*   *               * *   *         *               
*   *               * *   *         *               
*   *               * *   *         *               
*   *               * *   *         *               
*   *               * *   *         *               
*   *               * *   *         *               
*   *               * *   *         *               
*   *               * *   *         *               
*   *               *     *         *               
*   *               *     *         *               
*   *               *     *         *               
*   *                               *               
*   *                               *               
*   *                               *               
*   *                               *               
*   *                               *               
*   *                               *               
*   *                               *               
*   *                               *               
*   *                               *               
*   *                               *               
*   *                               *               
*   *                                               
*   *                                               
*   *                                               
*   *                                               
*   *                                               
*   *                                               
*   *                                               
*   *                                               
*   *                                               
*   *                                               
*   *                                               
    *                                               
    *
```